# USB drive cannot be accessed when starting script from scheduled task at logon

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-scheduler

I would like to start a script directly after the Windows (windows 10 enterprise 1809) user logon, and in the script I need to access an USB drive. Using the Run key in the windows registry works, however I noticed quite some delay (~10s) before the script is run.
To workaround, I created a task in the Windows task scheduler, running at user log on, which e.g. starts powershell.exe with the arguments '-command "ls f: | set-content d:\test.txt"'.
The task works fine when started manually, writing the text file. But when the task is run immediately after user logon (even with 1s delay), the file is not written. I assume the USB subsystem might not be available yet, and the registry Run key way might work since it is evaluated sequentially. 
The question is: is this suspected behaviour that access to usb devices does not work immediately after user logon with a scheduled task? Any way to overcome this, maybe filtering for an event like "USB subsystem initialized successfully"?

Comment: Often antivirus products will want to scan a USB drive before access is allowed. Do you have the same issue after disabling (or uninstalling if needed) your antivirus?

Comment: @DBADon yes, there is no antivirus solution installed